# See all the accesses from Powershell's Get-ACL

Tags: powershell, permissions

I came with this code to get the permissions of a file that to be put as a parameter.

```
foreach ($arguments in $args) {
    if (Test-Path $arguments) { #To see if the folder or file exists
        Get-Acl $arguments #If it exists
    } else { #If it doesn't exist
        Write-Host "The folder or file does not exist."
    }
}
```

Example: `PS c:\file> .\Script1.ps1 c:` <--- `c:` being the folder that I want to view the permissions.

[The result that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfNWC.png)

Is there a way to see all the other accesses instead of the dots ("...") after `FullControl` ?
Thanks!

Comment: You could target the property "Access" with `(Get-Acl $arguments).Access`. Would that be what you're looking for?

Comment: you are getting all the info. [*grin*] the _display system_ is truncating the _display_, not the actual data. if you want to see it all, send it to `Format-List`.

Comment: What are you wanting to end up with? Lee's comment about FL is likely to show you what you want to see, possibly more than. But if you're wanting to do more with it as an object then FL isn't what you want to use.